# How do I disable the monthly asking for saving sent-mail in Alpine?

Tags: linux, email, alpine-mail

Alpine always bugs me with its special offer of saving my sent mail monthly to a folder named like `sent-mail-monthname-year`. I want to not have this offer! I have other solutions for organizing my old mails.

Maybe I'm blind, but I did not find any option in the "`S Setup`" menu.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Under Setup > Config, take a look at Pruning Rule almost all the way to the bottom.

From the help within `alpine`:

> OPTION: Pruning Rule
>
> By default, Alpine will ask at the beginning of each month whether or not
>   you want to rename your sent-mail folder to a name like
>   sent-mail-month-year. (See the feature Prune Uses YYYY-MM to change the
>   format of the folder to sent-mail-yyyy-mm.) It will also ask whether you
>   would like to delete old sent-mail folders. If you have defined Read Message
>   Folder or Pruned Folders Alpine will also ask about pruning those folders.
>
> With this option you may provide an automatic answer to these questions. The
>   default value is to ask you what you'd like to do.
>
> The six possible values for this option are:
>
> ask about rename, ask about deleting
>         This is the default. Alpine will ask whether you want to rename the
>         folders and whether you want to delete each of the old folders.
>
> ask about rename, don't delete
>         Alpine will ask whether you want to rename the folders, but won't ask
>         about or delete old folders.
>
> always rename, ask about deleting
>         This means you want to always answer yes and have Alpine automatically
>         rename the folder if possible. You will also be asked about deleting
>         old folders.
>
> always rename, don't delete
>         This means you want to always answer yes and have Alpine automatically
>         rename the folder if possible. There will be no deleting of old
>         folders.
>
> don't rename, ask about deleting
>         This means you want to always answer no. Alpine will not rename the
>         folder. You will be asked about deleting old folders.
>
> don't rename, don't delete
>         This means you want to always answer no. Alpine will not rename the
>         folder. There will be no deleting of old folders, either.